# How to go through the deepest elements in an array of arrays?

Tags: java, foreach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] a={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}  ;
    for(int x:a)
        System.out.print(" "+x);
    }
}
```

Could someone please tell me how would I print each value in the array?

Comment: you should do another foreach

Comment: a is an array of arrays. So you need first to iterate through the inner arrays and then trough the values of them.

Comment: _give me a answer_ - Really? How about asking nicely.

Comment: I don't agree with the off-topic. It does have enough information to answer the question, which is testified by the answers already given. It may not be very polite/well formatted, but I don't think it's off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewG I think the problem is that the question is worded vaguely, leaving readers to infer what he probably means, and he doesn't tell us what results the code produces and how that differs from the desired results. I'm finding it *very* hard to justify casting a reopen vote on this one. Maybe I would if he accepted an answer, but until then, the mere presence of answers doesn't testify that there's sufficient information, because we don't know if they're based on correct inferences of what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could do it with one line and `for (int[] x : a) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use for each loop twice. In first loop you iterate over all the array and in the inner loop you iterate over all the integers in the outer array.

```
    int [][] a={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}  ;
    for(int []x:a){
        for(int y : x){
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're having a dual-dimension array, you need two loops:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] a={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}  ;
    for(int[] r:a) {
        for (int x:r) {
            System.out.print(" "+x);
        }
    }
}
```